# Android studio shows home directory instead of project

Tags: android-studio

I have problem with one (and only one) of my projects.
When I open it - it gets the whole directory tree from my disc instead of getting only project folder. I don't know how to describe it, so here is screenshot:
on the left - ordinary project, which shows project directory, on the right - this project.
[image]

Earlier this project was totally fine. Now even old commits cause this issue. I've already tried everything - I've reinstalled the whole system, I've installed Android studio without any side plugins or custom settings - result is the same. I've tried previous version of studio - didn't help.
I've tried this project on another 5 computers - one of them reproduced this bug.

Is there any suggestion - what can cause it?

Comment: don't open it, try importing it again

Comment: Importing what? As I said, I've already tried all standard solutions

Comment: file -> new -> import project, did you tried this?

Comment: Of course I did

Comment: invalidate the cache. Don't open Android Studio.  Delete the `.idea` folder of your project; open it again and let it re-index.

Comment: As I've said in my question - "I've reinstalled the whole system, I've installed Android studio without any side plugins or custom settings - result is the same". I've tried more than just invalidate cache and delete all generated and temporary files. Nothing helped

Answer (score 1):

In iml file find some strings like

```
<content url="file://$USER_HOME$/....">
<sourceFolder url="file://$USER_HOME$/...." />
```

They can produce such bugs. Try to delete them

Comment: This is not the full solution - these strings appear again after restarting of studio. But it helps to get typical look after deleting and rebuild. Thanks